# How I can find the list of transcription factor proteins involved in transcription of a specific gene?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, gene-expression, transcription, transcription-factor

I want to get the list of transcription factor proteins involved in the transcription of the human *SIRT1* gene. How can I access that?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far? My first instinct would be to check the literature.